# Filter options in a select_tag based on option selected in the previous select_tag (with a HABTM relationship)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 `select_tag` dropdowns in a `form_tag`. The first dropdown is for X and the second is for Y. X and Y have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

```
<%= select_tag 'x_id', options_for_select(@xs.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }) %>

<%= select_tag 'y_id', options_for_select(@ys.collect{ |u| [u.code + ": " + u.name, u.id] }) %>
```

Now, I want the options in the second dropdown to get filtered based on the option selected in the first dropdown.

I have the [Railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1zZ4Lgzf9s) for dynamic select menus, but it explains how to do it in a `form_for`. How do I do it in a `form_tag`?

Comment: It's essentially the same.  Take a look at the Rails doc. It show's you how to use it. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Comment: Thanks, if possible could you please give an example? I looked at the doc, but couldn't get too far.

Comment: It's in the docs but here you go.  You'll need to change this according to your models  <%= grouped_collection_select(:city, :country_id, @continents, :countries, :name, :id, :name) %>

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
<%= grouped_collection_select(:a, :b_id, @as, :bs, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: Good on you! user1175969